# Getting set up with a working contract without my knowledge. Is this possible?

Tags: contracts, contracting, employment-agreement, healthcare-industry

I'm a foreign trained physical therapist.

I am under a working contract with a company for 3 years. They gave me a job assignment through verbal (phone) agreement and I haven't signed any contract with the facility I am working with.

I specifically told them that I only wanted a 6 month to a year contract. I got to my job assignment and while I was asking for my vacation leave, I was told that they have set me up for a temp to perm contract and apologized for being "unclear" about it.

What labor law are they breaching with this? I was asking them if i could see my contract with the facility but they refused to let me see it because it was confidential info and I only need to know what they told me about the contract since they are representing me.

Comment: Where are you located? Local employment laws may apply here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us which country you are in.

Comment: you wont your employer is the Agency not the client your currently working for

Comment: To the anonymous user who attempted to edit, Texas is the name of a state in the US. You **must not** say "texas".

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two potential contracts in question here, and that's causing some confusion. Typically you would have signed a contract with the agency that hired you, and that would specify your vacation leave. You would have every right to see that contract, but apparently in this case there was no such contract. In that case, local employment laws probably specify the default conditions of employment.

The agency should also have a contract with the people you are actually performing the work for. I would not expect you to be able to see that contract, because it is competition-sensitive. In any case, it's not your obligation to fulfill that contract; it's the agency's obligation. If they have to arrange cover for you during your leave, that's their problem, not yours.

Comment: The word "contract" doesn't necessarily mean an actual physical document though.  In many jurisdictions a "contract" is just an agreement, and includes a verbal agreement.  That agreement might not be sufficiently detailed as to what the OP's rights and responsibilities are, in which case as mhwombat has said, local laws would likely have a default.